# Office Excel AddIn Custom Function Resource Download Error

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, office-dev-pnp

I used `yo office` to create a Excel AddIn with custom functions.

I made some changes based on following [Configure your Office Add-in to use a shared JavaScript runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/configure-your-add-in-to-use-a-shared-runtime) to use shared runtime.

After starting the project, I am able to check the shared runtime is running by checking the `go` text. But my custom functions did not work. it shows `#BUSY!` all the time.

I checked the error in `AppData\Local\Temp\OfficeAddins.log.txt`. There is no helpful information,

only content below:

```
11/29/2021 15:42:15 Unexpected  Resource    The server for this resource is unavailable.        
11/29/2021 15:42:15 Unexpected  Resource    The server for this resource is unavailable.        
11/29/2021 15:42:15 Medium  Resource    Resource Download Error Details: SolutionId=af84c00e-1e75-43c8-b0b8-5e68d915dfa4 , AppVersion=1.0.0.0       
11/29/2021 15:42:15 Medium  Resource    Resource Download Error Details: SolutionId=af84c00e-1e75-43c8-b0b8-5e68d915dfa4 , AppVersion=1.0.0.0       
11/29/2021 15:45:55 Verbose CustomFunctions [Execution] [Async] [Begin] Function=CONTOSO11.ADD1, Workbook=Excel add-in af84c00e-1e75-43c8-b0b8-5e68d915dfa4.xlsx
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Have the same exact problem. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolved my issue.

The problem turned out to be in the usage of `localhost` in manifest for the add-in. I changed my webpack-dev-server to listen on IP address of the desktop and use http protocol instead of https. After this change, the add-in registered in split second and I saw my custom function accessible in the sheet.

I originally tried to configure the local webserver to use "0.0.0.0" to listen to the network calls as well but apparently my company is not allowing any local servers running on the desktop to be accessed outside of the machine (local network) for security reasons therefore I chose the option to use the IP instead.

This is the devServer config entry in webpack I used:

```
devServer: {
  host: "xx.xxx.xxx.xxx",
  allowedHosts: "all",
  hot: true,
  headers: {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
  },
  port: 9000,
},
```

As I had said I also adjusted my manifest from `https://localhost:3000` which is the default to use `http://<IP of the host>:9000`

https did not work well since the certs were not matching host's logical IP address.

My original problem was slightly different than yours although the error message was exactly the same. My add-in was not loading at all and it was taking over 25 seconds to get an error from Excel on failed add-in installation reporting failure to load a required resource.

These are the errors I spotted in my Add-in log (OfficeAddin.log.txt)n:

```
8/19/2022 16:09:37    Medium    Resource    Resource Download Error Details: SolutionId=05c2e1c9-3e1d-406e-9a91-e9ac648541c3 , AppVersion=1.0.0.6        
8/19/2022 16:09:37    Unexpected    Resource    The server for this resource is unavailable.
```

The second challenge for custom functions executing properly was to configure shared runtime. There are two places in manifest + changes in webpack config.

Manifest:

1st place is right after `<HOST>` in main tag block

```
  <Requirements>
      <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.1">
          <Set Name="SharedRuntime" MinVersion="1.1"/>
      </Sets>
  </Requirements>
```

2nd place is right after `<HOST xsi:type="Workbook">` and inside `<Page>` tag:

```
<Host xsi:type="Workbook">
  <Runtimes>
    <Runtime resid="Taskpane.Url" lifetime="long" />
  </Runtimes>
  <AllFormFactors>
    <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="CustomFunctions">
      <Script>
       <SourceLocation resid="JS-URL" />
      </Script>
      <Page>
       <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url"/>
      </Page>
      <Metadata>
        <SourceLocation resid="JSON-URL" />
      </Metadata>
      <Namespace resid="Functions.Namespace" />
    </ExtensionPoint>
  </AllFormFactors>
```

Webpack adjustments are covered in the link you hinted.